# Cross Platform Code Organisation

Tags: c++, oop, singleton

I have this monitor class that gives access to instances of itself with a static function. When GetMonitor is called, the mMonitors map is searched and the instance is returned, if the instance doesn't exists, it is created.

```
class Monitor {
    public:
        static Monitor& GetPrimaryMonitor();
        static Monitor& GetMonitor(int number = 0);
        int GetXResolution();
        int GetYResolution();
        void SetXResolution(int resolution);
        void SetYResolution(int resolution);

    protected:
    private:
        Monitor(int number);
        static std::map<int, Monitor*> mMonitors;
};
```

My question is, when should I delete the instances of Monitor held in the map? Or should I take a different approach of allowing the user to create as many monitor instances he/she wants? This seems wrong because it would be as if they would be creating a physical monitor whereas my approach gives access to shared resources already available. Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I take a different approach of allowing the user to create as many monitor instances he/she wants? This seems wrong because it would be as if they would be creating a physical monitor whereas my approach gives access to shared resources already available

Yes, you absolutely should. For several reasons:

- You are giving the user the *abstraction* of a monitor, not a real physical monitor. So it's not necessarily wrong to have a different number of Monitor objects than you have actual physical monitors.
- Different users might have different numbers of monitors
- People may have "virtual" monitors, or perhaps mock implementations for testing, which never ever correspond to physical monitors at all.
- singletons are [just a plain horrible idea](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).

Comment: In response to singletons being horrible, I know that that is the general consensus but I think when they provide access to a shared resource they are okay. What do you mean by users might have different numbers of monitors? The monitor objects are created on the go at run time, if the 3rd monitor is requested and only 2 are plugged in then an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Since the last comment you have made me realise I am over complicating this! I will just allow users to create instances of Monitors. Is this approach better?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. It's simpler for you, easier to understand for the user of your code, and it's more flexible and powerful too. Why bother artificially constraining the number of instances that can be created? If the user wants exactly one instance, he'll just create one instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to stay away from singletons, especially if they're implemented with statics. The implications of this pattern aren't obvious at first, but can make things complicated later (e.g. if you have multiple binaries, DLLs, care about specific destruction order, etc.).

You should try to see if you can redesign things so that this Monitor instance can be passed around the code (sort of dependency injection) instead of doing it as a singleton (the most abused pattern in OO, really).

Comment: I think I will go with Jalf and just forget the singleton and make it into an object you can create. Thanks for the advice. Now to find out how to hook a monitor unplug event to my code... in linux :P Well wish me luck ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete an instance of a monitor (considering that you won't have that many monitors devices connected to your system, it won't be a problem). But if you really want to do so, you can delete them as soon as their respective devices are disconnected.

Regarding the creation of the instances, you can keep the same approach. You can instantiate a new object when the user asks for it (1) or when a new monitor device is connected (2). If it is possible to connect a monitor device to the system but do nothing with it in the context of your application I would go with (1). On the other hand, if every time a new monitor device is connected to the system your application, say, needs to get the device's resolution, I would go with (2).

Answer (score 0):

Whichever way, keep it consistent and obvious as to what they are supposed to do.

Does the number of monitors ever change?

If not, I would say you are better off keeping one version and maintaining ownership.  Don't let or make users destroy them.

If so, return a shared/auto pointer or something copyable.  I suspect that the latter is the right option unless creating and destroying your references to the internals is very costly.  This is speculative though.

Init/Cleanup functions in your main aren't beautiful or elegant, but they are effective and communicate your intention very directly.

Another (in my opinion, better) option is to not return an object at all.  Just expose static functions with monitor indices:

```
size_t GetNumMonitors();
void GetMonitorSize(size_t idx, int &x, int &y);
void SetMonitorSize(size_t idx, int x, int y);
```

If you really want the object design, hide it behind this (or similar) interface.  That frees the user from dealing with your implementation.